# You've got to be kidding me!

Tags: word, knowledge, word-search

Within this Boggle board is a set of eight words with a common theme. What are they/what is the theme?

```
V E D I  
N A K R  
H J O X  
O E S Y
```

To make a word in Boggle, connect at least three letters horizontally, vertically, or diagonally, without using the same letter (e.g. the bottom left "O") twice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Within this board you can find:

> the names of eight characters from the webcomic **[Homestuck](https://mspaintadventures.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Homestuck_characters)**.

These are:

> Dave, Dirk, Jade, Jake, Jane, John, Rose, Roxy.
>
>  All of these can be found in the grid starting from the 'D' on the top row, the 'R' on the second row, or the 'J' on the third, like so:
>  [image: Solutions marked on separate Boggle grids]
>
>  Regarding the title of this puzzle, @Deusovi helpfully points out in the comments that all eight named characters are referred to collectively as '[The Homestuck **Kids**](https://the-mystery-kids.fandom.com/wiki/Homestuck_Kids)', hence a connection to '***kid**ding*'...
>  <sub>In fact, as the OP comments below for completeness: John, Rose, Dave and Jade are known as the *Beta* Kids, while Dirk, Jake, Jane and Roxy are the *Alpha* Kids, the two groups that play different versions of the fictitious game [*Sburb*](https://mspaintadventures.fandom.com/wiki/Sburb) that exists within the Homestuck universe.</sub>

Comment: I don't think the title is a meme (or at least, it's one I've forgotten since I read it) -- I think it's just that these eight characters are collectively called "the kids".

Comment: Ah, thanks @Deusovi - googling the phrase appeared to bring up a lot of hits so I had assumed (though of course what *doesn't* bring up a lot of hits these days?!)

Comment: I picked the title for the reason @Deusovi mentioned, but it also is [a quote](https://www.homestuck.com/story/2074) as you said originally, which was a nice coincidence. :D Also for posterity, rot13(gur tebhc lbh zragvbarq ner gur "Orgn Xvqf" naq gur erfg ner gur "Nycun Xvqf", onfrq ba gurve irefvbaf bs gur svpgvgvbhf tnzr "Foheo").

Comment: Ah, okay - thanks @samm82 - I've incorporated your comment so it's 'on the official record' :)